# Empty cart by adding product to cart /magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3

i'm getting empty cart by adding product to cart.

what i already did:

- Set cookie lifetime: 86400
- Set cookie domain: http://www.domain.com/
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- php bin/magento indexer:reindexphp
- bin/magento cache:clean

but still the same.
what can i do else to resolve this problem?

my magento version is : 2.1.3
thanks

[image: empty cart]

Comment: Set Cookie Path -> /
Cookie Domain -> .<your domain>.com

Comment: Thanks to answer my question. Where to add my domain? I tried trough magento admin, but i got this error: " invalid path"

Comment: Hi, thanks @AnkitShah, everything seems now to working properly. :)